# Using ParseSwift .query().find() in an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb-query, parse-server

When using ParseSwift in an iOS app, I have the following kind of code working:

```
    do {MyCollection.query().find() {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let items):
              ... useful work here ...
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in \(#function): \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to see some sample code where the *query().find()* part is more selective. For some reasons, what I have tried on my own has always failed at this point. I must surely be missing some very simple detail, but I hope a few examples will make things more obvious.

I have looked at [this document](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/blob/a8b3d00b848f3351d2c61a569d4ad4a3c96890d2/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/11%20-%20LiveQuery.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L38-L95). But there is no example of this type:

```
MyCollection.query().find()
```

I can't even see a case using *find()*. And the syntax used for the selection within the *query()*: *query("score" > 9)*, isn't working when I want to use it, for some reason.

For example I want do something like the following, *parameter* is provided by the context and *field* is a field inside MyCollection pointing to another collection :

```
do {MyCollection.query("field" == parameter).find() {
  ......
}
```

And though the above isn't working. I can still do something like the following:

```
do {MyCollection.query().find() {
    result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let items):
        for item in items {
            if item.field?.objectId != parameter  {continue} // Eliminate useless item !
            // Keep item for useful work.
            ......
}
```

So performing the selection I want, but in a very inefficient manner, since I am getting the complete collection when I don't need it.

Comment: I didn't find any good doc, with examples. If you know of some please let me know.

Comment: I mean [THE documentation](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-Swift/api/index.html)

Comment: In the docs vadian linked, scroll down to "Usage Guide", click the link to "Swift Playground" It has examples of various queries with constraints.

Comment: Well, I have looked at the document you mention, which I had actually partly seen before. But there is no example relevant for me. I completed the post to give more details. Please take a look.